# Mysql Case with Or condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to write a case in mysql query which checks for null or 0 for a particular column

```
CREATE TABLE tblConfirmationStatus (Confirm_Status TINY INT)

INSERT INTO tblConfirmationStatus 
Confirm_Status
VALUES
(1),
(0),
(1),
({null}),
(0),
(1),
({null})
```

Required Output

**ConfirmStatus**

```
   Confirmed
   Not Confirmed
   Confirmed
   Not Confirmed
   Not Confirmed
   Confirmed
   Not Confirmed
```

0 or Null - Not Confirmed,  1-Confirmed

```
SELECT CASE Confirm_Status 
            WHEN NULL OR 0 THEN 'Not Confirmed' 
             ELSE  'Confirmed' END AS ConfirmStatus
  FROM tblConfirmationStatus;
```

Comment: NULLs are highly contagious, and transform any normal boolean/comparison operation into more NULLs. A case statement is simply a nice way of writing `if (confirm_status = null) ...`. You need `ISNULL()` to properly deal with it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's two options for CASE statements - the one you posted, or:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Confirm_Status IS NULL OR Confirm_Status = 0 THEN 'Not Confirmed' 
        ELSE  'Confirmed' 
       END AS ConfirmStatus
```

But you could probably use:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Confirm_Status > 0 THEN 'Confirmed' 
        ELSE  'Not Confirmed' 
       END AS ConfirmStatus
```

`NULL` is the absence of a value, so checking for values above zero should fall into the same category as zero.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT IF((Confirm_Status IS NULL OR Confirm_Status = 0), 
           'Not Confirmed', 'Confirmed') AS ConfirmStatus
FROM tblConfirmationStatus;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at using [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) operator.

> IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
>
> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the
>   context in which it is used.